# How to convert JSON to AVRO GenericRecord in Java

Tags: java, json, apache-beam, avro, data-conversion

I am building a tool in an Apache Beam pipeline which will ingest lots of different types of data (different Schemas, different filetypes, etc.) and will output the results as Avro files. Because there are many different types of output schemas, I'm using GenericRecords to write the Avro data. These GenericRecords include schemas generated during ingestion for each unique file / schema layout. In general, I have been using the built in Avro `Schema` class to handle these.

I tried using DecoderFactory to convert the Json data to Avro

```
DecoderFactory decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory();
Decoder decoder = decoderFactory.jsonDecoder(schema, content);
DatumReader<GenericData.Record> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
return reader.read(null, decoder);
```

Which works just fine for the most part, except for when I have a case of a schema that has nullable fields, because the data is being read in from a JSON format that does not include typed fields, so when it creates the Schema it knows whether or not that field can be nullable, or is required, etc. This produces a problem when it writes the data to Avro:

If I have a nullable record that looks like this:
`{"someField": "someValue"}`
Avro is expecting the JSON data to look like this:
`{"someField": {"string": "someValue"}}`. This presents a problem anytime this combination appears (which is very frequent).

One possible solution raised was to use an [AvroMapper](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary/tree/2.14/avro). I laid it out like it shows on that page, created the Schema object as an AvroSchema, packaged the data into a byte array with the schema using AvroMapper.writter()

```
static GenericRecord convertJsonToGenericRecord(String content, Schema schema)
  throws IOException {

JsonNode node = ObjectMappers.defaultObjectMapper().readTree(content);
AvroSchema avroSchema = new AvroSchema(schema);
byte[] avroData =
    mapper
        .writer(avroSchema)
        .writeValueAsBytes(node);

return mapper.readValue(avroData, GenericRecord.class);
```

Which may hopefully get around the typing problem with nullable records, but which is still giving me issues in the form of not recognizing that the AvroSchema is inside the actual byte array that I'm passing in (avroData). Here is the stack trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: No AvroSchema set, can not parse

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.avro.deser.MissingReader._checkSchemaSet(MissingReader.java:68)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.avro.deser.MissingReader.nextToken(MissingReader.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.avro.deser.AvroParserImpl.nextToken(AvroParserImpl.java:97)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:4762)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4668)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3691)
```

When I checked the avroData byte array just to see what it looked like, it did not include anything other than the actual value I passed into it. It didn't include the schema, and it didn't even include the header or key. For the test, I'm using a single K/V pair as in the example above, and all I got back was the value.

An alternative route that I may pursue if this doesn't work is to manually format the JSON data as it comes in, but this is messy, and will require lots of recursion. I'm 99% sure that I can get it working that way, but would love to avoid it if at all possible.

To reiterate, what I'm trying to do is package incoming JSON-formatted data (string, byte array, node, whatever) with an Avro Schema to create GenericRecords which will be output to .avro files. I need to find a way to ingest the data and Schema such that it will allow for nullable records to be untyped in the JSON-string.

Thank you for your time, and don't hesitate to ask clarifying questions.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem?